# Lua: Get the literal name of the parameter

Tags: string, function, lua

For example,

```
function test (a)
    name = nameof(a)
    print(name)
end

test(def) --should print "def"
```

Are there any lua tricks to implement something similar to the above?

---

Not that anyone needs to explain *why* they want to do something; some people get grumpy if they aren't  given a real-life example. So:

```
local function registerTestSuite(suite)
   if (LUnit) then
      LUnit:AddTestSuite(
            HotNReady.."_"..GetVariableName(suite), --HotNReady_PizzaTestSuite
            suite);
   end;
end;
```

Comment: Why do you want to do this? What problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: I want to be able to write declare_object object1. Right now I have to write declare_object "object1". declare_object is a function.

Comment: I'm not sure how what you're asking for would help you to lift the braces in a function call.

Comment: +1 for useful question. This is exactly what i wanted to achieve today.

Comment: You can get all variable/object names and values with `for k,v in pairs(_G) do print(k,v) end`. If the variables are in a table, you can use the same code snippet to get the names of all objects in the table.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What you asking for is not possible in pure Lua.

If you **really** need this, try fiddling with [Metalua](http://metalua.luaforge.net/).

Comment: I'm not sure why answers to edge cases so often need to include radical skepticism as to whether the questioner **really** needs to do the thing they took the time to ask a question about. Upvoted nonetheless.

Answer (score 2):

Try using the [debug library](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.1/manual.html#5.9).

You can use **`debug.getlocal ([thread,] level, local)`** to get information about a local variable, including its name.

Comment: It's semi usable. The "local" in debug.getlocal ([thread,] level, local) is actually the index into an array of variables declared local in the stack denoted by level.

Comment: Yeah, you're right.  Its not really the general purpose solution you are looking for.

Comment: Don't forget that the `debug` module is strongly discouraged in production code that is not a debugger.

Comment: A good recommendation, but I'm not sure if is suitable for what I need, personally. I just want to include arg names to go with the error message for a value that fails a test in a validation function.

Answer (score 1):

Now you can also use [icecream-lua](https://github.com/wlingze/icecream-lua) to get the literal name of parameters:

```
local icecream = require('icecream')

local foo = 1
local bar = 'abc'

icecream(foo, bar)
```

The output looks like this:

> ic| foo = 1, bar = abc