# How can you pass a variable to a function and change the original variable within the function?

Tags: lua

I'm here to ask you how can a function set a variable passed by a parameter:

```
y = 4
test(y)

function test(x)
   x = 3
end
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: I'm curious as to why you need this?

Comment: You simply need to get into a different mindset with Lua (and not just Lua -- each language has a mindset of its own, even if some languages share a common 'thought' of doing things).  Lua's way is to allow a function to return multiple values and this in turn can be used to update any parameter by simply returning the modified value, and re-assigning it (from outside the function) to the needed variable(s).  In my view, this is a 'cleaner' way of doing things.  The way you describe (allowed in many languages) is actually a bit risky in the sense you may not expect an implicit variable change.

Comment: In addition to the philosophical points made about language and function design, technically your premise is incorrect: you are not passing a variable, you are passing a value derived from an expression. Your expression just happens to be very simple `y`. Then inside the function `y` is a parameter and therefore a different local variable. There are more philosophical arguments about changing the value of a parameter or any "variable" for that matter.

Comment: One with Pascal-like language background may be used to the possibility of declaring parameters with 'var' (in effect pointers to the actual variables, but without the explicit use of pointer syntax as in C), and then any updates of those variables from inside the function update the original variable passed in the function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From my current knowledge of Lua this wouldn't be possible with purely Lua. You'd have to dive into http://metalua.luaforge.net/ to achieve this. Maybe I'm wrong, but I don't see a way without grabbing the variable name which from my knowledge isn't possible with pure Lua unless you provide it.

I am curious to as why you actually need this, as I don't know why I cannot recommend the best solution, but you can simply return the value instead:

```
function test()
    return 5
end

x = 0
print(x) -- prints 0
x = test()
print(x) -- prints 5
```

If you can also settle with passing the variable as a string, you can also do something like this:

```
function test(y)
    _G[y] = 5
end

x = 0
print(x) -- prints 0
test("x")
print(x) -- prints 5
```

Comment: Thanks, only to know if it is possible, most languages do that today and I was asking myself if it is possible :)

Comment: @MatteoGuglielmetti maybe you can get the original variable name by using `debug` but I wouldn't recommend it. Lua is a very simple language, don't expect it to do what some major languages do ;)

Comment: @MatteoGuglielmetti http://stackoverflow.com/a/1416843/5557841 - So, it is possible, but not recommended.

Comment: @MatteoGuglielmetti most languages prohibit this, at least for simple values. Structures (structure in wide sense, here f.e. lua tables) usually behave different

Comment: Thank you guys I didn't know that before, but why it is not reccomanded?

Comment: @MatteoGuglielmetti simply because it's a debugger and meant for debugging. If you cannot achieve something without using `debug` then it's probably not supposed to be achieved. https://www.lua.org/pil/23.html - *"[..] some of its functionality is not exactly famous for performance. Second, it breaks some sacred truths of the language [..]"*